# How to pass a URL parameter in an ajax() call

Tags: jquery

I have a single page (products) which responds to URL parameters and displays the information accordingly.

Here are some examples:

- `http://www.mysupersite.com/products`
- `http://www.mysupersite.com/products/buy`
- `http://www.mysupersite.com/products/buy/computers`

These are user-friendly URLs. The URL parameters are "buy" and "computers".

I need to pass the parameters **from the current page** in an ajax() to my server so that it knows what types of information to send back e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cfc/getsomeproducts",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        //psuedo code below...
        ProductCategory: "buy",
        ProductType: "computers"
    }
})
```

To clarify, if I were on `/products/buy`, I would need to send `ProductCategory: 'buy'`. If on `/products/buy/computers`, `ProductCategory: 'buy', ProductType: 'computers'`.

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The code you show will work just fine.  Do you just want to send the AJAX call to `http://www.mysupersite.com/products/buy/computers`?  Can you explain what doesn't work with what you have?

Comment: Those aren't *"URL parameters"*. URL (or query) parameters come after a `?` and are separated by `&`, eg `/some/uri?category=buy&type=computers`

Comment: They are URL parameters. You can't see the  `? ` and the  `& ` because its rewritten to look nicer. They're hidden so to speak.

Comment: Maybe if you showed how they were *rewritten*, you might get better suggestions. Anyway, the client-side doesn't know how your server treats requests. All it sees is a URI with no query parameters

Comment: Well its as simple as this.  `http://www.mysupersite.com/products.cfm?ProductCategory=buy&ProductType=computers` <-- This is the true page that loads.

Comment: Then simply change the `url` parameter in your code above to `/products.cfm` and use `GET` instead of `POST` and it should work as required

Comment: Do you just want to send a request to `'http://www.mysupersite.com/products'+ProductCategory+'/'+ProductType`?  Are you just asking how to concatenate the strings into the URL?

Comment: I don't understand Phil. I have to post the values to the server for it to return me the products I want.

Comment: Then use `POST`. I fail to see what the problem is

Comment: @RocketHazmat The request is going to `/cfc/getsomeproducts` which is a server function that will return me products in HTML format. This function needs to know what my URL parameters are so that it can return the correct set of products.

Comment: @Phil, the problem is how to pass to the server in that ajax() call the URL parameters that are present in the calling page (products.cfm)

Comment: @volumeone: Then just do what @Phil said and change `POST` to `GET`.

Comment: @volumeone What **exactly** is `/cfc/getsomeproducts` looking for in the request, `GET` parameters or `POST` parameters?

Comment: Wait, so you want to pass information from the **current** URI? If so, why didn't you just say that?

Comment: @Phil its current doing something like this in pseudo-code. `<if URL.ProductCategory Exists or URL.ProductType Exists, return records of Products Where ProductCategory=URL.ProductCategory and ProductType=URL.ProductType>`

Comment: @volumeone so it's been at least 10 years since I did ColdFusion but to me, that looks like it's expecting `GET` parameters

Comment: @Phil yes exactly. the current URI makes a call to the server using Ajax() asking for products to be loaded onto the page.

Comment: @volumeone I've edited your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Phil ok thats great. I did write "I need to pass the parameters from the current page" in the question before the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = document.location.pathname;
var values = url.split("/");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cfc/getsomeproducts",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        ProductCategory: values[2],
        ProductType: values[3]
    }
})
```

Comment: You have put the URL in the variable url. But how do you get in there in the first place without manually typing it in? I need to get it from the address bar

Comment: @volumeone `document.location.pathname`

Comment: Why `split` more than once? Just use `values[4]`, etc

Comment: So how does it split after the first `/` and then the second `/` and so on? A URL could be like `mysupersite.com/products/sell/accessories`

Comment: @Phil My mistake, fixed.

Comment: @volumeone I am not understanding.

Comment: Its splitting when it encounters a `/`. So will it split at the `http://` as well?

Comment: @volumeone If you load the page `http://www.google.com/1/2/3/file.ext`, values[0] = "", values[1] = 1, values[2] = 2, values[3] = 3, values[4] = file.ext, so forget the http://, because I am using document.location.pathname.

Comment: I see, thats great. I'll give it a go now thank you. If the user goes to just the base page like this `http://www.mysupersite.com/products` then this means the URL parameters are NULL. Is this ok or will the data{} part of the ajax() fail?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a solid convention for URL params you can just parse the URL before your ajax call then send an array as data.  On the backend, just parse the array in the order your convention defines. Something like:

```
var myUrl = 'http://my.url/param1/param2',
delimiter = '/',
start = 3,
params = str.split(delimiter).slice(start),


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/cfc/getsomeproducts",
dataType: "html",
data: {
    params[]: params
}
})
```

Comment: You've put the URL into the myURL variable. How do you get the URL from the address bar into there without manually typing it in?